# Does Apache Kafka 0.9.x not generate csv for metrics ByteInPerSec and ByteOutPerSec

Tags: apache-kafka, metrics

I have Apache Kafka in version 0.9.x with enabled built-in KafkaCSVReporter for metrics.

```
kafka.metrics.polling.interval.secs=5
kafka.metrics.reporters=kafka.metrics.KafkaCSVMetricsReporter
kafka.csv.metrics.dir=/tmp/kafka/metrics
kafka.csv.metrics.reporter.enabled=true
```

I have set directory for generated csv files and start processing of data (producer  client). In my csv directory there are some files:

```
BytesRejectedPerSec.csv
LeaderCount.csv
PurgatorySize.csv
RequestQueueTimeMs.csv
ResponseQueueTimeMs.csv
ResponseSendTimeMs.csv
ThrottleTimeMs.csv
TotalFetchRequestsPerSec.csv 
TotalTimeMs.csv
```

Unfortunately there aren't these, which are the most needed: ByteInPerSec and ByteOutPerSec. Intresting seems to be the fact, that when I connect by JMX with Kafka server using jconsole, I can see in MBeans tab metrics ByteInPerSec and ByteOutPerSec, but csv files are not generated for these metrics. Why ? Should I set any additional properties in config file ? Is it possible to get these metrics in csv format ? I want to say, that for me intresting are Kafka server metric (not producer/consumer metrics)
Thanks in advance for any help.
Regards 
Marcin

Comment: Did not find the answer, but I know that these values are shown in Streams Messaging Manager (disclaimer: I am an employee of Cloudera). So it must be possible to get them out somehow.